# Bulk Insert Where IN (....)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have a comma separated list of ID's I need to insert into a table like:

---

```
Table Name: tblFilterUsers
-
- FilterUserID int (pk)
- FilterGroupID int
- UserID int
```

---

The insert I have looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO [tblFilterUsers] (FilterGroupID,UserID)
    SELECT '10',UserID FROM [tblUsers] WHERE [UserID] IN (1,2,3........)
```

The problem is the comma separated list contains over 80,000 ID's and the query takes too long and times out.

Is there an easier and quicker way to insert a comma separated list of ID's into a table like this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to add IDs to temporary table then use join with tblUsers in the insert statement?

Comment: How are you generating the list?  Often the easiest solution is just to do all the work in the database.

Comment: If you just run this piece how long does it take? `SELECT '10',UserID FROM [tblUsers] WHERE [UserID] IN (1,2,3........)`

Comment: @user3394380 Temporary table takes too long too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm generating it on a complicated filter in ASP.

Comment: @JChao, it takes over 300 seconds to insert the 80,000.

Comment: @Aki In what format does your web app generate these IDs? Could you provide some code on how you used temporary table?

Comment: I would guess that you should change the application to do the list generation inside the database.  If a single query doesn't suffice, a stored procedure would probably work very well for the processing.  Passing long lists of ids (in the tens of thousands) between the application and the database just doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I found the best solution to my problem. As I'm not able to take advantage of SqlBulkCopy or code the actual insert logic within SQL (as @Gordon-Linoff suggested), I ended up using a clever store procedure that would allow inserting comma separated values into the database fast.

This reduced the time taken for 80,000 inserts down to 6 seconds or so.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE unpack_with_manyselect
             @list      nvarchar(MAX),
             @tbl       varchar(30),
             @delimiter nchar(1) = ',' AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX),
             @q1     char(1),
             @q2     char(2)
SELECT @q1 = char(39), @q2 = char(39) + char(39)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT ' + @tbl + ' EXEC(' + @q1 + 'SELECT ' +
               replace(replace(@list, @q1 COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2, @q2 + @q2),
                       @delimiter COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2,
                       ' SELECT ') + @q1 + ')'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Usage:

```
EXEC unpack_with_manyselect '9, 12, 27, 37','tblResults',','
```

---

Found it on a great article that can be found here:
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#listtoselect

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time thing I usually enter the data into Excel they way I need the data.  Within MS SQL Studio Mgmt, right click the table select "Edit Top 200 Rows", then copy the rows/columns of data from Excel and then paste into MS SQL Studio Mgmt.

Comment: It's not one time. This is a filtered report I generate as part of my web app. This is extreme scenario where a customer has a lot of data.

Comment: Then I would use the string.Split to split csv string into an Array.  Create a Datatable insert the array of Ids then use SqlBulkCopy to insert Datatable into MS SQL

Comment: I would like to use SqlBulkCopy, but I'm using classic ASP for this project, so no real way of creating a datatable unless I use FSO to create Excel file for it which I'd prefer not to do. Any ideas?